# border-radius on div and opacity on image inside not working right in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using a div who has a border-radius , inside the div is an image who has opacity and on Firefox that is working great but in Chrome border-radius is not working. 
See the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WHNcd/2/)

Is there a fix for that problem in Chrome ?

Update:
I diden't say that I'm using [this metod](http://iw3b.info/348/programing/center-image-in-fixed-size-div-center-thumbnail-image/) to center the image inside the div so I cant use border-radius on image it must be used on div

Comment: hmmm, seems like the opacity is interfering. Remove it and the radius works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
.thumb img{
opacity:0.7;
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
border-radius: 7px;    /*this8*/

}
```

this works , even with opacity

see [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WHNcd/5/)

Answer (score 0):

if you apply the opacity to `.thumb` and border-radius to the `img`, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/WHNcd/4/

that means you can use a wrapper for the image if needed

Comment: I diden't say that I'm using this metod [link](http://iw3b.info/348/programing/center-image-in-fixed-size-div-center-thumbnail-image/)  to center the image inside the div so I cant use border-radius on image it must be used on div